# Generating Sudoku Puzzle

Tags: c, algorithm, backtracking, sudoku

I'm trying to write a piece of code which generates for me a valid sudoku puzzle.

**My algorithm:**

1. initiate all fields with 0
2. respect the rules and set 20 random values from 1-9 to random fields
3. solve the puzzle with the back tracking algorithm

**My problems:**

1. Sometimes it generates a valid sudoku puzzle in under 1 second.
2. Sometimes it can't generate a valid sudoku and I get an error, which is ok because I can go back to step 1 in my algorithm.
3. Sometimes it can't generate a valid sudoku and I get an error but it takes about 2-3Minutes, which is not ok.

How can I solve my problems?
Especially problem 3.
Can I just count the seconds and if it takes more than 5 seconds just go back to step 1 of my algorithm?

Or does anyone have a better idea?

thanks in advance.

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 9
#define UNASSIGNED 0


typedef enum {false, true} bool;
typedef struct { 
    char number;
    bool editable; 
} GRID;

void print_sudoku(GRID **g){
    char row=0, col=0;
    for(row=0; row<N; row++){
        for(col=0; col<N; col++){
            printf("%d ", g[row][col].number);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


GRID ** create_sudoku_grid(){
    char i, row, col;
    GRID **g = (GRID **) malloc(N * sizeof(GRID *));
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        g[i] = (GRID *) malloc(N * sizeof(GRID)); 
    }

    for(row=0; row<N; row++){
        for(col=0; col<N; col++){
            g[row][col].number = UNASSIGNED;
            g[row][col].editable = true;
        }
    }
    return g;
}



bool find_unassigned_field(GRID **g, int *row, int *col){
    for (*row = 0; *row < N; (*row)++) {
        for (*col = 0; *col < N; (*col)++) { 
            if (g[*row][*col].number == UNASSIGNED){
                return true;    
            } 
        }
    }
    return false; 
}

bool validate_row(GRID **g, int row, int num) { 
    for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
        if (g[row][col].number == num) {
            return false; 
        }
    }
    return true; 
} 

bool validate_col(GRID **g, int col, int num) { 
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        if (g[row][col].number == num) {
            return false; 
        }
    }
    return true; 
} 


bool validate_box(GRID **g, int row, int col, int num) { 
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) { 
            if (g[r+row][c+col].number == num) {
                return false; 
            }
        }
    }
    return true; 
} 


bool validate_field(GRID **g, int row, int col, int num){
    bool valrow, valcol, valbox, valunassigned;

    valrow = validate_row(g, row, num); 
    valcol = validate_col(g, col, num);
    valbox = validate_box(g, row - row%3 , col - col%3, num);
    valunassigned = g[row][col].number==UNASSIGNED; 
    return (valrow && valcol && valbox && valunassigned);

}


bool generate_sudoku(GRID **g) { 
    int row, col; 

    // If there is no unassigned location, we are done 
    if (!find_unassigned_field(g, &row, &col)) {
        return true; // success! 
    }

    // consider digits 1 to 9 
    for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++) { 
        // if looks promising 
        if (validate_field(g, row, col, num)) { 
            // make tentative assignment 
            g[row][col].number = num; 

            // return, if success, yay! 
            if (generate_sudoku(g)) {
                return true; 
            }
            // failure, unmake & try again 
            g[row][col].number = UNASSIGNED; 
        } 
    } 
    return false; // this triggers backtracking 
} 

void random_init_grid(GRID **g){
    int row, col, num;
    srand(time(0));

    for(int cntr=0; cntr<20;){
        row = rand() % N;
        col = rand() % N;
        num = rand() % N + 1;
        if(g[row][col].number == UNASSIGNED){
            if(validate_field(g, row, col, num)){
                g[row][col].number = num;
                cntr++;
            }
        }

    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GRID **g = create_sudoku_grid();
    random_init_grid(g);

    if(generate_sudoku(g)){
        printf("OK\n\n");
    } else {
        printf("\nNOT OK\n\n");
    }
    print_sudoku(g);
}
```

Comment: You could do that, yes.

Comment: Does your algorithm check if there is *only one* possible solution?

Comment: Have you investigated to see which part of your algorithm is slow? Does the backtracking search sometimes take a long time, or is the problem that you're generating a lot of grids which get rejected because they have no solution (or more than one solution)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
I don't understand how #1 is a problem; You say that #2 is okay.  You do *not* give a reproducible problem for #3.  Instead of randomization, hard-code a starting grid that gives you this problem.  Trace the slow points in your code.  *Then* you have a good posting.

Comment: OT: The posted code dynamically allocates an array of arrays to store a grid of size N, which is a constant known at *compile time*. You could just declare that grid as `GRID g[N][N]` and pass around a pointer `GRID g[][N]`.

Answer (score 0):

Sudoko is a computationally hard problem possibly in the order of 10^100 using brute force and ignorance.  It could take a lot longer than 2-3 minutes!  Sometimes, because of number layout, it is easier than that.

In one approach, you could count your iterations, and give up if it exceeds them.  Your key bit is the block where you recursively call generate_soduko() -- if you end up in here too many times you are in trouble.

To that end, I changed your program put a 1s alarm on its execution, counter the number of times in that block; and if the alarm expires, print the counter and exit; if it doesn't print the counter for reference at the end.   On my machine, 1s == 500,000 iterations.

```
*** sud.c~  2019-12-06 14:30:21.000000000 -0500
--- sud.c   2019-12-06 14:30:57.000000000 -0500
***************
*** 1,10 ****
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  #define N 9
  #define UNASSIGNED 0

- 
  typedef enum {false, true} bool;
  typedef struct { 
      char number;
--- 1,21 ----
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
+ #include <signal.h>
+ #include <unistd.h>
+ #include <time.h>
+ 
+ volatile long  counter;
+ void alrm(int signo) {
+   char buf[64];
+   int n;
+   n = sprintf(buf, "failed after %ld iter\n", counter);
+   write(2, buf, n);
+   _exit(1);
+ }

  #define N 9
  #define UNASSIGNED 0

  typedef enum {false, true} bool;
  typedef struct { 
      char number;
***************
*** 106,111 ****
--- 117,123 ----
      for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++) { 
          // if looks promising 
          if (validate_field(g, row, col, num)) { 
+       counter++;
              // make tentative assignment 
              g[row][col].number = num; 

***************
*** 139,145 ****
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
!     GRID **g = create_sudoku_grid();
      random_init_grid(g);

      if(generate_sudoku(g)){
--- 151,161 ----
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
! 
!     GRID **g;
!   signal(SIGALRM, alrm);
!   alarm(1);
!     g = create_sudoku_grid();
      random_init_grid(g);

      if(generate_sudoku(g)){
***************
*** 148,151 ****
--- 164,168 ----
          printf("\nNOT OK\n\n");
      }
      print_sudoku(g);
+     printf("iter = %ld\n", counter);
  }
```